# Non-constant Linear Boolean Function

Tags: functions, cryptography

How can we prove that any non-constant linear Boolean function is balanced ? I know that any non-constant affine function is balanced. But i cannot expend this for Boolean function.

Answer (score 0):

if you can prove that any non constant affine function is balanced.then you have proved that any non-constant linear Boolean function is balanced.
beacuse linear functions are aspecial cae of affine functions where a0=0.